# How to get the link of jquery autocomplete script files

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-plugins, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am looking to download the JQuery Autocomplete, but the websites seems not running properly. It says bad gateway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`jquery.autocomplete.js` is a part of the JQuery UI framework.  You can download that library at the official website located here - http://ui.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 15):

You can still download it from following sites

https://github.com/agarzola/jQueryAutocompletePlugin

and

http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-autocomplete/

Comment: Shouldn't SO be kept up to date so that someone looking for an answer to a question doesn't have to ask it again two years later? You know, like a repository of questions and answers and not a mailing list.

Comment: The first one is most recent version of standalone autocomplete...

Comment: @alestanis What's wrong if one answers in old question. Hi answer helped me rather the accepted answer.

Comment: PLEASE ANSWER OLD QUESTIONS. It saved me a bunch of time and potentially another duplicate question

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for http://UI.jQuery.com.

Comment: It's amazing how often your posts appear in the list of low quality posts. - http://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts?pagesize=15&filter=day

Comment: @jjinguy: What else is there to say here?

Comment: I can't argue that you didn't perfectly answer the question.  It just surprises me every time a see a mod diamond in the list.